# Get a list of all members from Sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

When I run `Get-MsolUser | Get-Member | Out-GridView` in PowerShell

I get an error `Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet` .

I can't find anything in Google which points me in the right direction for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error since the command:

```
Get-MsolUser | Get-Member | Out-GridView
```

throws exception if the connection has not been established. Having said that, you could consider the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

Use `-InputObject` parameter:

> Specifies the object whose members are retrieved. Using the
>   InputObject parameter is not the same as piping an object to
>   Get-Member. The differences are as follows:
>
> -- When you pipe a collection of objects to Get-Member, Get-Member gets the members of the individual objects in the collection, such as
>   the properties of each string in an array of strings.
>
> -- When you use InputObject to submit a collection of objects, Get-Member gets the members of the collection, such as the properties
>   of the array in an array of strings.

```
Get-Member -InputObject Get-MsolUser | Out-GridView
```

**Solution 2**

Since `Get-MsolUser` cmdlet requires the connection to be established, execute the command [`Connect-MsolService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194123.aspx) first and then:

```
Get-MsolUser | Get-Member | Out-GridView
```